# Change hover style under custom component in styled-component

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I have a below structure.

```
<Nav>
  <Title/>
  <DropDown />
</Nav>
```

`<Nav />` is a class component and I need to show Dropdown when I hover over `<Nav />`.

Here is the code snippet of `<Nav />`.

```
export default class HeaderLink extends React.PureComponent {
...
}
```

Here is the code snippet of `<DropDown />`.

```
const Container = styled.ul`
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    transform: translateY(20px);
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;

    ${Nav}:hover & {
        opacity: 1;
        visibility: visible;
        transform: translateY(-2px);
    }
`;

const DropDown = ({ items }) => (
    <Container>
        {items.map(({ title, url }) => (
            <a href={url}>{title}</a>
        ))}
    </Container>
);

DropDown.propTypes = {
    items: PropTypes.array.isRequired
};

export default DropDown;
```

This is not working but I figured that If I define `<Nav />` component as a styled-component, it works

i.e. `const Nav = styled.ul''`

But it's not working for the class component.

Any thoughts on this?

Thanks.

Comment: You gotta style the ultimate generated HTML and not the pure components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're attempting to use a parent as a selector, which is not currently possible in CSS (see: [Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)). Your `:hover` should be on your `Nav` component, which in turn targets the appropriate child element.

See example CodeSandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/x9lmkply4.

Comment: Thanks. it works but `&:hover { > ul { ... } }`. you specified `ul` but can we point a custom component directly? so we can implement this in a styled-component way.

Comment: Yes, if you're using the latest version of styled components then you can use interpolation. E.g. `${ChildComponent} { ...rules }`. I've updated the sandbox appropriately.